# Would a druid's magic armor (+1, or the like) be able to be converted to barding during wild shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape, armor

A previous discussion from about 7 years ago covered essentially the same topic, but I want to see if any new info has come to light or if opinions have changed since then

[Does magic armor resize with wild shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64370/does-magic-armor-resize-with-wild-shape)

---

For a druid, wildshape allows equipment to be either worn or absorbed, with equipment being dropped if it cannot be 'worn' and isn't absorbed.

> PHB pg. 60-61 "You choose whether your equipment falls to the ground in your space, merges into your new form, or is worn by it. Worn equipment functions as normal, but the DM decides whether it is practical for the new form to wear a piece of equipment, based on the creature’s shape and size. Your equipment doesn’t change size or shape to match the new form, and any equipment that the new form can’t wear must either fall to the ground or merge with it. Equipment that merges with the form has no effect until you leave the form."

For items like rings and most articles of clothing, it's infeasible to continue to wear them because most wildshapes are distinctly not humanoid shaped and tend to be too large/small for necklaces, belts, cloaks etc. However, there are rules for certain creatures to wear armor, i.e. barding for warhorses. In addition, the rules for magic items are that they may/do resize to fit the wearer, although how quickly or easily it does is left vague:

> DMG pg. 140: "In most cases, a magic item that's meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they magically adjust themselves to the wearer" [rare exceptions for items that are made for certain races such as drow armor or dwarven armor]

Therefore, I wonder: if a druid has some form of magical armor, a kind that may magically adjust to the wearer, and they wildshape into a warhorse, would the armor be able to become barding?

RAW, this seems so close to being possible, but with 'specific trumps general' and the sentence 'Your equipment doesn't change size or shape', this may supercede magic items resizing rules thus making it not possible

RAI, the lack of equipment size change in wildshape may be interpreted for mundane items only, and if a magic item is possible/feasible to wear for the wilshape (necklace, cloak, barding/armor for warhorses) it may be allowed

RAF, it seems awesome and doesn't really break much because warhorses have less HP than a more 'optimal' wildshape choice like a bear or the like.

Comment: If there is something that you'd like a revisit on - the better path is to bounty the question that's been asked before and not to reask it. If you'd like, I'd be happy to do that for you.